# Unexpected format when writing to file in c++

Tags: c++, file

this is my code

```
ofstream Team_txt("Team.txt", ios_base::app);
cout << "Please enter team name: ";
cin >> Team_Name;
cout << "Please enter team Id: ";
cin >> Team_ID;
cout << "Please enter Captain name: ";
cin >> Team_Captain;
cout << "Please enter Total_Score name: ";
cin >> Total_Score;
Team_txt << Name << ' ' << Team_ID << ' ' << Team_Captain << ' ' << Total_Score << endl;
Team_txt.close();
```

I expect to see

[image]

but I see:

[image]

in the second image there is a space before each line and an empty line on the top

Comment: You're opening the file in append mode (`ios_base::app`) which could be the cause of the leading newline if the file already contained data. You output `Name` not `Team_Name` - check that `Name` isn't just a space or something silly.

Comment: `Team_txt << Name << ` instead of `Team_txt << Team_Name << ` is a typo, is it?

Comment: oh, it was a typo I don't know why the compiler didn't give me error maybe because I use classes
I change it and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line :

```
Team_txt << Name << ' ' << Team_ID << ' ' << Team_Captain << ' ' << Total_Score << endl;
```

name is not defined in your code, check it maybe you need `Team_Name` instead of `name`.

Comment: This question was resolved in a manner likely to be unhelpful to future visitors (typographical error, there's a few close votes pending on this question wrt that) - for questions like this, it's standard decorum to [leave it to be roomba'd](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) after it's inevitably closed - posting answers can delay or prevent this from happening.